# Image in base64 ignores EXIF Orientation

Tags: html

Uploaded image has EXIF Orientation: Rotate 270 CW, if I use `<img src="path.jpg"/>`, then browser shows the image correctly. But if I use `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,..."/>` it is displayed rotated, how can I fix this?

No JS solution, need to fix it with html, because this is used in email template

Changing to inline images is also problematic at the moment, would be perfect if I could keep it as base64 image and solve the orientation issue

Comment: Maybe you could use a CSS transform (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like :

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,..." style="transform: rotate(270deg);" />
```

And pass the EXIF Orientation as rotate value.

Documentation : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: not sure if it is supported by email clients... will test and will post an update here

Comment: Otherwise I found this : http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_auto-rotate_digital_photos_to_their_proper_orientation/exifautotran_code

Comment: yeah, I probably can add server-side conversion, but I was trying to figure out why the image as src displayed correctly, while same image as base64 displayed rotated. If I save base64 image, they are exactly the same, but in browser they are displayed differently

Comment: I think browser/client doesn't interpret base64 rotation. I don't know why !? but everybody search for the same thing.

Comment: if I resize the image using imagick, then base64 image of that thumbnail is displayed properly. I decided to go with that solution for now